# File size more than allocated nfs space

Tags: nfs, disk-usage

W.R.T [du space more than the disk size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230382/du-space-more-than-the-disk-size)

I am seeing a similar situation wherein nfs mounted share has been allocated 100G ( as seen in df ) however there seems to be a file with size 2.1TB inside it.

OS is Centos 6.9

I understand there can be a variance in sizes reported by `df` and `du` however i am confused as to why so much difference is there.

From where is the file getting space if the allocation is much lesser than the actual file size ?

Comment: You may want to add the output of `df -hTa <path-to-nfs-share>` and `stat <2.1TB-file>`.

Comment: If your file consists of 2.1TB of `NULLs`, then there is no problem. The file system will see that there's no actual data and the space on the physical disk will be minimal. This is where Thomas' suggestions will give you more information to work with.